# Read child process stdout in a separate thread with BOOST process

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-thread, boost-process

I have a main program that uses boost process library to spawn a child process that prints

```
Hello World !
```

on its stdout every 5 seconds.

I would like to read/monitor the stdout of the child process in the main process when it becomes available along with performing other operations within the main program.

I have tried out the examples for `boost asynchronous IO` (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html) but all these seem to block the main program until the child process has exited.

Do we need to read the childs stdout in a separate thread ? Can someone please provide an example where the main program can do other things at the same time instead of blocking for stdout from th child ?

Comment: Please show your code. The `bp::child` from the link you provided should do the trick.

Comment: The example code blocks (I think) due to the call to [`boost::asio::io_service::run()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run/overload1.html).  Depending on your needs you might want to replace that with ``intermittent'' calls to [`boost::asio::io_service::poll`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/poll/overload1.html).  However, without seeing your code (or knowing precisely *why* blocking is a problem) it's difficult to comment further.

Comment: @G.M. If you use asynchronous call chains, there's no need for interleaving the event loop, in the spirit of asynchronous operations.

Comment: I'm answering this type of question quite regularly here. I like to provide different ideas in the answers, so compare and pick from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-process?sort=newest&pageSize=50

Comment: @sehe Point taken.  I should've ``brushed up'' on my `boost` before commenting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I have tried out the examples for boost asynchronous IO (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html) but all these seem to block the main program until the child process has exited.

Look again. All the samples under [Asynchronous I/O](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html#boost_process.tutorial.async_io) should help you select a method that works for  you.

> Do we need to read the childs stdout in a separate thread ? Can someone please provide an example where the main program can do other things at the same time instead of blocking for stdout from th child ?

No, you don't *need* to. Though you *can* and depending on what you're trying to achieve, it might be the easiest thing to do.

### Synchronous

You failed to tell us what you want to be able to do, so let's assume you just want the output printed:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6fd0283d9c0c98de)</kbd>**:

```
bp::child c("/bin/bash", std::vector<std::string> { "-c", "for a in {1..10}; do sleep 2; echo 'Hello World !'; done" });
c.wait();
```

That's synchronous, so you can't do work in the meantime

### Using a Reader Thread

That's like:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a76e3298e410e4fe)</kbd>**:

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/process/async.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bp = boost::process;

int main() {
    bp::ipstream output;
    std::thread reader([&output] {
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(output, line))
            std::cout << "Received: '" << line << "'" << std::endl;
    });

    bp::child c("/bin/bash",
        std::vector<std::string> { "-c", "for a in {1..10}; do sleep 2; echo 'Hello World ('$a')!'; done" },
        bp::std_out > output);

    while (c.running()) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2793));
        std::cout << "(main thread working)" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "(done)" << std::endl;
    c.wait();

    output.pipe().close();
    reader.join();
}
```

Prints (**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a76e3298e410e4fe)</kbd>**):

```
Received: 'Hello World (1)!'
(main thread working)
Received: 'Hello World (2)!'
(main thread working)
Received: 'Hello World (3)!'
Received: 'Hello World (4)!'
(main thread working)
Received: 'Hello World (5)!'
(main thread working)
Received: 'Hello World (6)!'
(main thread working)
Received: 'Hello World (7)!'
Received: 'Hello World (8)!'
(main thread working)
Received: 'Hello World (9)!'
(main thread working)
Received: 'Hello World (10)!'
(main thread working)
(done)
```

### Asynchronous IO

Using no threads (well, just the main thread), could look like:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7874ca9c396a12a2)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/process/async.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/high_resolution_timer.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace bp = boost::process;

struct OtherWork {
    using clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

    OtherWork(boost::asio::io_context& io) : timer(io) { }

    void start() {
        timer.expires_at(clock::time_point::max());
        loop();
    }

    void stop() {
        timer.expires_at(clock::time_point::min());
    }

  private:
    void loop() {
        if (timer.expires_at() == clock::time_point::min()) {
            std::cout << "(done)" << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        timer.expires_from_now(std::chrono::milliseconds(2793));
        timer.async_wait([=](boost::system::error_code ec) {
            if (!ec) {
                std::cout << "(other work in progress)" << std::endl;
                start();
            } else {
                std::cout << "(" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
            }
        });
    }

    boost::asio::high_resolution_timer timer;
};

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context io;
    bp::async_pipe output(io);

    OtherWork mainwork{io};

    bp::child c("/bin/bash", std::vector<std::string> { "-c", "for a in {1..10}; do sleep 2; echo 'Hello World ('$a')!'; done" },
            bp::std_out > output, io, bp::on_exit([&mainwork,&output](auto...) {
                    output.close();
                    mainwork.stop();
                }));

    std::function<void()> readloop = [&,buffer=std::array<char, 32>{}]() mutable {
        output.async_read_some(bp::buffer(buffer), [&](boost::system::error_code ec, size_t transferred) {
                if (transferred) {
                    std::cout << "Received: '";
                    while (transferred && buffer[transferred-1] == '\n') // strip newline(s)
                        --transferred;
                    std::cout.write(buffer.data(), transferred);
                    std::cout << "'" << std::endl;
                }

                if (ec)
                    std::cout << "Output pipe: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                else
                    readloop();
            });
    };

    mainwork.start();
    readloop();
    io.run();
}
```

Prints **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7874ca9c396a12a2)</kbd>**

```
Received: 'Hello World (1)!'
(other work in progress)
Received: 'Hello World (2)!'
(other work in progress)
Received: 'Hello World (3)!'
Received: 'Hello World (4)!'
(other work in progress)
Received: 'Hello World (5)!'
(other work in progress)
Received: 'Hello World (6)!'
(other work in progress)
Received: 'Hello World (7)!'
Received: 'Hello World (8)!'
(other work in progress)
Received: 'Hello World (9)!'
(other work in progress)
Received: 'Hello World (10)!'
Output pipe: End of file
Child exited with code=0(Success)
(Operation canceled)
```

Comment: In the reader thread example, I am unable to get how the reader thread is printing since the stdout of the child process isn't redirected to the ipstream object when spawning the child process.
Changing this to `bp::child c("/bin/bash", std::vector<std::string> { "-c", "for a in {1..10}; do sleep 2; echo 'Hello World ($a)!'; done" }, bp::std_out > output);` returns the below output:
`Received: 'Hello World (1)!'
(main thread working)
Received: 'Hello World (2)!'
(main thread working)
Received: 'Hello World (3)!'
execution expired`

Comment: You're right. I had some copy and past errors. Fixed now. (See [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a76e3298e410e4fe)) "Execution expired" is due to time limiting on Coliru